# Excel - Find cell, navigate to column to the left, get last non-empty value of that column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vlookup, lookup

I am trying to create a formula that does the following:

1) Finds a cell based on a text value (i.e. C2 contains the domain, "example.com," search for that) from another sheet inside the same workbook, with a range of A1:ZZ1.

2) Once the cell match has been identified, navigate to the column left of the matched cell.

3) Grab the last non-empty value of that column.

I have been using this code to do it manually, but it requires entering the column myself, and doesn't adjust if column are deleted from the sheet.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(Sheet1!A:A<>""),Sheet1!A:A)
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value i want to search appears in `Sheet1` and the searching area is in `Sheet2`. You could modify the below formula and try:

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(INDIRECT("Sheet2!" & SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(C2,Sheet2!1:1,0)-1,4),"1","") & ":" &SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(C2,Sheet2!1:1,0)-1,4),"1","")  )<>""),INDIRECT("Sheet2!" & SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(C2,Sheet2!1:1,0)-1,4),"1","") & ":" &SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(C2,Sheet2!1:1,0)-1,4),"1","")  ))`

**Sheet1:**

[image]

**Sheet2:**

[image]

Comment: Wow, that is truly amazing, it actually works! But it does seem to be pretty slow when replicating over a lot of uses... regardless, it does indeed work and I've selected your answer is correct. If you can think of a more "lightweight" way to accomplish it, please let me know!

Comment: @Joe one faster solution is VBA